# Are mixed class/protocol type constraints allowed in Swift protocol extensions?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

Is it possible, in any version of Swift, to extend a protocol with mixed class/protocol type constraints? For example, I would like to extend `Protocol2` only when `Self` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and conforms to `Protocol1`.

```
protocol Protocol1 {}
protocol Protocol2 {}

//What I imagine I could do, but it does not compile
extension Protocol2 where Self: UIViewController, Protocol2 {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
extension Protocol2 where Self: UIViewController, Self: Protocol2 {}
```